# Adding interpollated rows to a data.table based on a condition

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, interpolation, rows

I have a data set as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(year = structure(c(1993, 1993, 1993, 1997, 1997, 
1997, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2003, 2003, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2017, 2017), comment = "year"), 
    State = structure(c("Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", 
    "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", 
    "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", 
    "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas", 
    "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kansas"), class = "AsIs", comment = "state"), 
    State_Abbr = structure(c("KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
    "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
    "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS"), class = "AsIs", comment = "state_po"), 
    Party = structure(c("republican", "democrat", "Other", "republican", 
    "democrat", "Other", "republican", "democrat", "Other", "republican", 
    "Other", "democrat", "republican", "Other", "republican", 
    "democrat", "Other", "democrat", "republican", "Other", "republican", 
    "Other", "democrat", "republican", "Other"), class = "AsIs", comment = "party"), 
    Percentage = structure(c(0.626967802302283, 0.310289787269175, 
    0.0627424104285421, 0.620238525135418, 0.344369476385061, 
    0.035391998479521, 0.652661584410013, 0.315878201849193, 
    0.0314602137407939, 0.825223659651155, 0.174776340348845, 
    0.274872411697912, 0.691627798218281, 0.033499790083807, 
    0.600583964516102, 0.364584658335329, 0.0348313771485682, 
    0.263785496339944, 0.70094378363408, 0.0352707200259761, 
    0.531464769317622, 0.468535230682378, 0.322381278217064, 
    0.621752543886607, 0.0558661778963293), comment = "totalvotes"), 
    cyear = structure(c(1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 
    1998L, 1998L, 1998L, 2002L, 2002L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2014L, 2014L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L), comment = "year")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

A small part of the data is shown below:

[image]

Although Senate Elections generally take place every two years, Kansas did not have an election in 1994 (`cyear`). I would nevertheless like to know estimates of the division of parties in 1994. As a result I would like to add a row. Adding the rows I solve as follows:

EDIT:

```
# Gets the rows and row numbers where a row should be added

Numbers <- setDT(DT)[, newcolumn := as.integer(year - shift(year) > 2), .(State, Party)]
Numbers[, uniqueID := .I]  
Numbers[newcolumn==1, newcolumn := uniqueID] 
Numbers[, uniqueID := NULL]
sub <- setDT(Numbers)
sub <- setDT(sub)[!is.na(newcolumn)]
sub <- setDT(sub)[newcolumn!=0]

# X is a dataframe of the rows that should be added
X <- sub
# X is a vector of where the rows should be added
sub <- sub[,newcolumn]

# The function that insert the row - r = rownumber
insertRow2 <- function(existingDF, newrow, r) {
  existingDF <- rbind(existingDF,newrow, use.names=FALSE)
  existingDF <- existingDF[order(c(1:(nrow(existingDF)-1),r-0.5)),]
  row.names(existingDF) <- 1:nrow(existingDF)
  return(existingDF)  
}

# for-loop that gets the row number from the vector, and the corresponding row from the data-frame and adds to the new data-set.
for (i in sub){
  newrow <- X[i,]
  Numbers <- insertRow2(Numbers, newrow, sub[i] )
}
```

I think I still have a problem in my last for-loop. Can anyone help me out?

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @sindri_baldur. Is it not clear from the desired result? Kansas year 1995, was missing, I want add that row, and interpolate, without doing it manually. In the desired result I added rows 1220-1222 manually.

Comment: In my EDIT I tried to add duplicate rows, where the new rows should be (that way I have information about what those rows should be). But it does not work.

Comment: @Tom it's still pretty confusing... if you make it more concise, you'll get more answers!

Comment: @Werner My apologies for the poor explanation. Essentially it is what Vincent proposed.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Essentially what Vincent suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to (a) fill-in missing years, and (b) *carry-forward* information from the previous year to fill-in the information for those missing years. This is one form of interpolation, but there are many others.

To achieve this, you could:

1. Create a "rectangular" dataset with every possible combinations of State-Party-Year.
2. Merge your dataset into that rectangular data
3. Sort by State-Party-Year
4. Use the `na.locf` function from the `zoo` package to carry-forward information to fill-in the new rows.

```r
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# rectangular data
dat = CJ(year = min(DT$year):max(DT$year),
         State = unique(DT$State),
         Party = unique(DT$Party))

# merge
dat = merge(dat, DT, all.x=TRUE)

# sort
dat = setkey(dat, State, Party, year)

# carry-forward
dat = dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE)), 
          by=.(State, Party)]

# print
head(dat)
#>    year  State Party State_Abbr Percentage cyear
#> 1: 1993 Kansas Other         KS 0.06274241  1992
#> 2: 1994 Kansas Other         KS 0.06274241  1992
#> 3: 1995 Kansas Other         KS 0.06274241  1992
#> 4: 1996 Kansas Other         KS 0.06274241  1992
#> 5: 1997 Kansas Other         KS 0.03539200  1996
#> 6: 1998 Kansas Other         KS 0.03539200  1996
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is definitely very close. I have two small questions. When using it on my actual data, I got the error: `Error in [.data.table(dat, , :=(State_Abbr = na.locf(State_Abbr),  : 
  Supplied 29 items to be assigned to group 3 of size 43 in column State_Abbr.` Do you have any idea why this might happen? Secondly, in my actual data (I subsetted my actual data for your code) has a lot more columns. Is there an easier way to write the carry forward, without specifying it for every column? In any case, thank you very much for your help

Comment: I think the error might have something to do with starting NA's? That there are not enough interpolated values for all NA's?

Comment: I modified the answer. You can use `lapply` to carry forward all variables, and `na.rm=FALSE` to avoid dropping starting missing values.